# reducir instancia de clase de reflexión

Tags: php, refactoring

Tengo una instancia de reflexión de clase a la que luego le extraigo el valor de la siguiente forma:

```php
    $reflectionClass              = new ReflectionClass($subobject->class);
    $publicprops[$key]->{'value'} = $reflectionClass->getProperty($subobject->name)->getValue(new $subobject->class);
```

Pensaba que podía reducir la expresión con:

```php
    $publicprops[$key]->{'value'} = new ReflectionClass($subobject->class)->getProperty($subobject->name)->getValue(new $subobject->class);
```

Pero no me lo permite y me arroja error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR) in
C:\xampp\htdocs\dev\BOH\BOH-Basic-Output-Handler\src\Commons.php on
line 94
```

¿Qué necesito agregar para que sea correcta la reducción?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya esta resuelto cuando se crea una instancia

```
new ReflectionClass($subobject->class);
```

o la que sea de cualquier clase esta se debe ejecutar primero antes que nada para que esto se cumpla hay que meterla entre paréntesis:

```
(new ReflectionClass($subobject->class))->getProperty($subobject->name)->getValue(new $subobject->class);
```

esto provoca que php resuelva lo que esta entre paréntesis primero; en este caso la instancia.